# Swift convert unix time to date and time gives incorrect year

Tags: swift, unix-timestamp

I am getting time string from server but when I convert it to local time its giving incorrect

year like **52635**

**My code is-**

```
if let dateVal = (model.insert_date){
            if dateVal != ""{
                
                //dateVal = "1598859638000"
                let dt = Double(dateVal)
                let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970:dt!)
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E MMM d yyyy"
                //dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en")
                let outputDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
                print(outputDate) //Fri Nov 6 52635
               
                cell.lblName.text = outputDate
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your code is correct. Check with your timeStamp.
and what is the expected year for this given timeStamp?
is it "Fri Aug 28 2476"?

Comment: Divide it by 1,000.

Comment: @bestiosdeveloper Its showing **GMT: Monday, 31 August 2020 07:40:38** If I am checking it online.

Comment: @iDeveloper Whatever source you're using to check is expecting the time in milliseconds, or at least it's smart enough to recognize that you've entered a time in milliseconds and do the right thing. El Tomato and mahan have clearly given the right answer: you're providing a timestamp in milliseconds to a method that uses seconds as the unit of measure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divide  timestamp by **1000**, because Date uses seconds and the timestamp was generated with milliseconds and use **TimeInterval** instead of **Double**.

```
    let dateVal = TimeInterval(1598859638000) / 1000.0

    
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(dateVal))
    print(date, "date", date.timeIntervalSince1970)

  
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: "en")
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E MMM d yyyy"
    let outputDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    print(outputDate) // Mon Aug 31 2020
```

I guess your timestamp is generetd in a Java / Kotlin Applicatin. In java,
**(new Date(1598859638000l))** yields **Mon Aug 31 2020**.

Comment: You should cast both values in the dateVal calculation to TimeInterval/Double to preserve the sub-second accuracy of the timestamp: `let dateVal = TimeInterval(1598859638000) / 1000.0`. Granted in the example the timestamp has zeros in all the sub-second places, but some timestamps might actually have millisecond accuracy.